# CMOS inverter with capacitive load design

Tags: mosfet

I have been tasked with making a CMOS inverter with a range of capacitive load between 1pF to 1uF, with the TN0704 and TP0604. I am not really sure how to account for the range of capacitances. Should I find the mean and design a circuit based on that, or do I have to do something else?

Comment: You design it for the worst case scenario i.e. 1 uF.

Comment: @Andy aka, hence do just have to I choose a resistor at the NMOS and one at the PMOS to have equal charging and discharging times?

Comment: I don't know because that isn't given as a requirement. All you said was "CMOS inverter" and there is nothing implicit in "CMOS inverter" that says the the charge and discharge should be the same.

Comment: Is there a max rise/fall time or frequency spec?

Comment: @Justin Nope, no such requirement.

Comment: @Andy aka, Yeah, the statement that was given to me said the exact same thing, so I assumed that the requirement was to have equal rise and fall times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any CMOS inverter can drive ANY capacitive load, but you may not like the SlewRate.

I = C * dV/dT

and the output drive strength sets the SlewRate.

However, there will be HEATING, and driving a large capacitor is the same as driving a SHORT CIRCUIT, given the 10 nanosecond thermal time constants of tiny FETs.